# How to export application metrics out of PCI environment

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card, token, payment-gateway

I am building a credit card tokenization/payment-processing service. As these services need sit in pci-compliant environment, I find it hard to export the application metrics & logs. Anyone knows how is this usually handled?

For detail:
I am writing the service in Java and using StatsD to record the application metrics. I want to export these metrics out of the PCI environment to graphite, as such I could monitor and set up alerts for the services.

Any ideas are welcomed!

Answer (score 3):

You'll just have to follow your PCI procedures. You'll have to create a change that allows the statsd server to exist. A manager will have to review/ok the change.

It will cause a few dependent changes and activities:

- add a new statsd server to the DMZ (network change, system change, system hardening, configuration standards)
- add the statsd service and graphite service to the allowed services on the network
- record the new server in your equipment overview
- update the network diagrams
- Allow selected servers to access the statsd service. Be sure to practice least privilege principle. (firewall change)
- Allow the statsd service to (only) access the remote graphite service (firewall change)
- If applicable, update procedures to add "allowing access to the statsd service" as a default configuration for new machines. Be sure to practice least privilege principle.
- Consider wether this change constitutes a significant enough change to need a penetration test
- Kick off an internal vulnerability scan which includes the statsd server
- Alter the application to include statsd support (application change, code review)

Comment: Don't forget the software review process for the custom Java service.

Comment: @NSSec got it! So essentially, I need deploy a statsD daemon inside DMZ and then make firewall change to allow the graphite service outside DMZ to be able to communicate with the statsD daemon inside the firewall?

Comment: That's basically the technical part of things. You should also have your statsd implementation in your java application reviewed by a peer to make sure you're not sending PANs instead of timestamps :P.